# PHP access to global variables from an HREF='file.php'

Tags: php

I have a menu that is in an iframe.  The user selects an option from the menu to log in and after the credentials are verified (using mySQL) (via a call to href='login.php')  -  I need to access several variables (such as the object handle to the mySQL connection ($dbconnection), user id ($userid) value. I have declared these variables as globals and they appear= to be inaccessible from the launch of href="other.php" menu option.    I have tried to put these as $GLOBALS  and the same results - they are inaccessible from the launch of href="other.php" menu option.

Passing these variables in the href call via the use of ?  and  &  is not a good solution (and besides you cannot pass an object such as a Data Base handle. I need these variables in other files I open from the menu via the href.

What is the best way to have this functionality?

Jack

Comment: Are you trying to access php variables that you defined on the parent page in the iframed page? If that's the case, you can't. Those are two totally different requests.

Comment: [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variables are available during the entire execution of the script but they are not persistent. Each invocation of a PHP script is independent of other invocations. What you need can be solved using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: The variables are set up in the iframe itself when the call is  handled by the login.php.   Are there any ways to gain access to the php variables in another href that is in the same iframe when invoked by the href from the menu selection? Is the invocation of another href starts with no idea of what is in the $GLOBALS?

Comment: OK axiac, I would like a sample code of how I would use the Session.  I do start up in index.php with a call to       session_start();

Comment: I use the following after calling session_start()

Comment: I use the following after calling session_start()  in  the frame where my login.php is being invoked:
            $_SESSION['loggedinuserid']= $user;   then in the module called access.php which is called via an href in the same frame I am not getting the value when I issue an echo on the $_SESSION['loggedinuserid']  - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One more data point, the object to the opened MySQL data base does not seem to be accessible (even if I store it in the $_SESSION) in other php files.  Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem.  In order to pass variables to called PHP files via the HREF  I had to put these variables in the SESSION global.  I then did a $enc=session_encode() which encodes into a string all the user defined session variables and then I passed the string value to the called file via the use of the ? after the file being called.  In the file that I called, I pulled the passed  encoded SESSION string via a $GET  and then used the value from the $GET to call session_decode ().  That seemed to work.  I am also thinking of hashing and salting this encoded string so that it is not easy to hijack it.